# Why .val() is always empty (Jquery)?

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have a problem with an Input.

here's my html/php code :

```
$dotation = ($ig["dotation"]) ? $ig["dotation"]: '<input type="text" class="datepickerIG" name="igDota" size="8" value="test"/>';
            $bo .= '<tr style="background-color: black;">
                     <td class="dot">' . $dotation . '</td>
                     <td class="modif" ref="' . $ig["id"] . '"><a href="#">Modifier</a></td>
```

here's my js code :

```
        var dot_cha = $(this).parent().find('.dot').val();
```

my question is, why var dot_cha is always empty ?!
when I use .html insteed of .val, I get the right  so, where's my error ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you call `var dot_cha = ...` because `this` will refer to the caller object. Besides `.dot` does not have any values because it is `td`.

Answer (score 3):

.val() grabs the value attribute of a input-element. ".dot" is a td and doesn't have a value-attribute.

What exactly is it you want dot_cha to be? If its the input you are after, this would work.

```
$(this).parent().find('.datepickerIG').val();
```

If it is the text of the td .html() or .text() will give you this.

Answer (score 1):

`val` retrieves the value of `input` and other tags which have this attribute. In your case, `.dot` is the class of a table row which has no attribute `value`... So you have to use `.text()` or `.html()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the problem is a `<td>` doesnt have a value, it contains HTML.

That would be why .html works and .val doesnt.

You use .val on inputs that have values, but `<td>` is not an input its just a HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

`val()` is to be used with form elements (such as `input`, `textarea` etc...), not with elements.

You need to get the `innerHTML` or `innerText` of the element.

Something like:

```
var dot_cha = $(this).parent().find('.dot').text();
```

Though you need to ensure you have one element - as you may be getting a collection of elements.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. In the case of  elements, the .val() method returns an array
>   containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns
>   null.

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`.

`val` is used on form elements. Since `.dot` is a `td` element (which is not a form element) using `val` on it will not work. To get the contents of any element other than a form element, use [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0):

The [doc here](http://api.jquery.com/val/) says

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

You're right .html works since in your case you have a td, and you should use

```
$(".dot").html()
```

Hope it helps